# How can I create a cloud backend to update my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloud, updates, backend

I have a news application that i am in the process of building, and of course news updates a lot, so I have to constantly update my stories, so I need a backend of some sort that will let me update my stories over the air without updating the actual app.

I found Parse.com and they have some awesome stuff, but with the way my app is built I don't think I can use them.

I will have to update UIImageviews, UItextviews, and the names of Buttons. With Parse I can only seem to find help regarding the PFQueryTableViewController, which I could use this, but that requires completely recoding and some redesigning of my app to fit into that.

So unless there's another way, I guess I will suck it up and get to work.

So is there a simpler way to do this, or maybe a better service that works more towards what I'm describing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking basically is how to do network communication.  It sounds like to me you can do what you want with just Parse.  You just store the images and text and then call the information from the parse backend when you are loading.  From there you can update the UITextViews, button names, and UIImageViews however you want dynamically (using the .text, setTitle, and .image properties and methods respectively).  You could also use Amazon S3 for image storage... but the API is less well documented for that.

This is probably your best bet, unless you really want to delve in more deeply and learn how to use NSURLConnection or AFNetworking to communicate with a back-end that you build on a django, ruby, etc. server that you host yourself on a server.

Comment: I think you're right about Parse, I have just had some doubts because I can't find any documentation or tutorials related specifically to what I'm doing. Could you possibly point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yeah, definitely.  This is images: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#files/iOS
This is how to save objects (such as text):
https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects/iOS
This is how to retrieve them intelligently (https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS)

I really recommend just reading through the parse documentation.  It's really well written and you will be able to adapt it to what you are doing.

Comment: Awesome I really appreciate it! I had looked through the parse documentation before but I couldn't find any of this for some reason. That's exactly what I needed.